# how to get parent item of selected item outlineview Swift

Tags: swift, nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller

I have multilevel hierarchy in my outlineview. I am able to get the selected item and it's parent item using below code.

```
  func outlineViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let outlineView = notification.object as? NSOutlineView else {return}

    if let item = outlineView.item(atRow: outlineView.selectedRow) as? CubeData{
      
         // Getting the parent item
          if let parentItem = outlineView.parent(forItem: item) as? CubeData{
            print("Parent Item value:", parentItem.node)
          }
        print("Selected Item value:", item.node)
       }
}
```

But not able to get all the grand parent items.

For example **A->B->C->D** is my hierarchy and whenever I am selecting "D" I am able to get "C" and "D". I want all the parent items. Any help?

Comment: Does `CubeData` have `parent` property?

Comment: @Willeke, ye we have an array of parent property.

Comment: Why can't you get the grandparents?

Comment: @Willeke, I don't know how to get it. I am not able to link child with grandparent.

Comment: The grandparent is the parent of the parent. If you get the parent with `let parentItem = item.parent` then you get the grandparent with `let grandparentItem = parentItem.parent`.